# Getting a Count of Contacts from Outlook Office REST API - Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, msdn, outlook-restapi

I'm having difficulty distinguishing between Microsoft's absurd amount of conflicting API documentations: outlook.office.com, outlook.office365.com, microsoft graph, Azure, and so on

I've successfully authenticated and pulled contacts, but I can't seem to get a count to know when I should stop pagination.

I've been using:

```
Access Token url: 
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token;
Successful Contact url: 
    https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts;
```

Their [REST API Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#contact) says I should be able to simply make a call to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/$count` but this keeps returning a plaintext MIME type with body `-1`.

If anyone has struggled with this before or knows what's going on, I'd appreciate a point in the right direction - and hopefully some easy points for you!

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to Jason below for his helpful support. Using the sandbox I was able to reproduce the issue with the following:

Logged in to my account -> Received Access Tokens -> Made a GET call to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/$count`

**Request Headers:**

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/$count HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none
User-Agent: PlayGroundAgent/1.0
Authorization: Bearer [standard-access-token]
client-request-id: 8f605[client-id-obscured-for-security]7289
X-AnchorMailbox: [email-address-removed-for-security on stackOverflow]
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: de95eaa8-95a7-40bb-b0f9-ced7270f0433
X-CalculatedBETarget: SN1PR05MB1998.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: SN1PR05MB1998
X-BEServer: SN1PR05MB1998
X-FEServer: SN1PR0501CA0035
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 657E0491C29D46978D8DD3B01B9F93A3 Ref B: DDDD64A109F4E842A8213F038BFDD5FA Ref C: Fri Aug 19 09:20:05 2016 PST
Cache-Control: private
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 16:20:05 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=6ca5fc4df96e458e8b879de61aa574ef; expires=Sat, 19-Aug-2017 16:20:05 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

-1
```

---

**2nd Edit**: It looks like `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts?$count=true` returns `@odata.count": -1` as well, even as it returns valid array of contacts.

---

**3rd Edit: Working version** (Same method was used as the errors above)
Url: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/$count

**Request Headers:**

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/$count HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none
User-Agent: PlayGroundAgent/1.0
Authorization: Bearer [access-token]
client-request-id: a7954db3-[client-id]-7a6e2e74dd9c
X-AnchorMailbox: [same-email-as-above]
```

**Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: 8c5db16b-3023-4968-9bdc-3d5ecac12ecb
X-CalculatedBETarget: SN1PR05MB1998.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
OData-Version: 4.0
X-DiagInfo: SN1PR05MB1998
X-BEServer: SN1PR05MB1998
X-FEServer: SN1PR0501CA0019
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 0574E46DB720491FBCEF23B73428F191 Ref B: FA4529229719F069B9D019E4D53E9200 Ref C: Fri Aug 19 09:42:55 2016 PST
Cache-Control: private
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 16:42:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=63a1de916a4c48be88569f05ce0361a7; expires=Sat, 19-Aug-2017 16:42:55 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

29
```

Hope these help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you're having trouble! There's a couple of things going on here.

It's troubling that you're getting a negative number back from the `$count` call. If you go to https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net and login with your account, do you get the same result from that call?

For paging, if all you want to do is get all the results, it is better to not rely on the `$count` value. Instead, you should use the `@odata.nextLink` value that comes back in the response to get the next page. Of course if you're trying to indicate to a user how many pages are there before getting all the results, the `$count` is the way to do that.

Paging is controlled by the page size (the `$top` parameter) and the "cursor" (the `$skip parameter). If you're making a call to`/me/contacts`with no parameters, then you're getting the default page size of 10 and default cursor of 0. You can use the`$top` parameter to request more results per page.

The `@odata.nextLink` value will always return a URL you can use to get the next page based on the page size you specified in `$top` (or 10 if you did not specify). Here's the value from doing `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts`:

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?%24skip=10"
```

This skips you ahead 10 results (based on the default page size of 10).

And here's the value from `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?$top=20`:

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/?%24top=20&%24skip=20"
```

If there are no more pages, the `@odata.nextLink` value will not be present in the response. So you can use that as your indicator to stop paging.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that sandbox. It's reassuring to see it looks like I'm using the same authentication path (based on the urls) as the sandbox. The first time I tried it, yes it returned a count, but a couple of subsequent attempts produced the `-1` as well! Not sure what the common thread is yet that triggers the fail...
On a related note, thank you for your help with the pagination, my concern is that this limits me to forward and backward only, I'd like to show page numbers that would allow a user to jump from page 1 to 4, but I'd need to know page 4 actually exists.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you'd need the count. If you can reproduce it in the sandbox, would you mind posting the full response (including headers)? I'd like to run it by our devs.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a bit hit and miss. My App managed to get the count for about 2 calls, then back to `-1` without any changes. I am able to get the Sandbox to fail occasionally as well. Responses are too long to fit in comments so I'll make an edit to the question.

Comment: Hi Jason, not sure if you're still following this, hoping you might be - have you noticed an uptick in errors recently? One of my API's is now returning 404's and even the sandbox is giving me
```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts?$top=50 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PlayGroundAgent/1.0
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
client-request-id: {request}
X-AnchorMailbox: censored@email.com
```
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000005;reason="The user specified by the user-context in the token does not exist.";error_category="invalid_user"